# OnClickListener and fragments causing application crash

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I'm trying to use fragments to programatically change the text on a screen. To do this I'm setting up an on click listener on a text view and then if it's clicked starting a  fragment manager, replacing the current fragment with the new fragment. However, this causes my app to crash when it's started.

From reading the crash report it seems like the error is happening at `tv1.setOnClickLIstener`...

Finally, Android Studio keeps giving me a type mismatch when I use fragment or support fragment. That is why you see `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //begin transaction
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //replace the contents of the container with the new fragment
    ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, new SplashScreenFragment());

    ft.commit();


    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.whatIsHumanTrafficing);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.placeHolder, new whatIsHumanTrafficing());
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

}

}
```

XML from activity_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/placeHolder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


</FrameLayout>
```

XML displayed before click:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.piatt.worksafe.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/splashScreenId"
>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Work Safe!"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
     />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What is Human Trafficing?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/whatIsHumanTrafficing"
    android:clickable="true"

    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How do I get safe labor?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/whatIsHumanTrafficing"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/howDoIGetSafeLabor"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How do I check that my job / job offer is legal?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/howDoIGetSafeLabor"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/checkLegality"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="How can I get help?"
    android:layout_below="@+id/checkLegality"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/getHelp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="About us"
    android:layout_below="@+id/getHelp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/aboutUs"
    />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

XML to be displayed after click on text view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Human Trafficing Is:"
    android:textSize="36sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confiscation of travel documents"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HTdescription1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/HTdescription1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"


    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Unregistered Labor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HTdescription1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/HDdescription2"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Isolation from friends and family"
    android:layout_below="@+id/HTdescription2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/HDdescription3"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    />



</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment named human trafficking that I'm trying to inflate:

```
public class whatIsHumanTrafficing  extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.what_is_human_trafficing, container, false);
}
```

}

Comment: post your xml here

Comment: I may have over done it but I included the relevant xml

Comment: is there any fragment named `whatIsHumanTrafficing`?

Comment: post your stack trace.

Comment: @indramurari added it to the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You have used `activity_main` in your `MainActivity` as follows

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and you are accessing `whatIsHumanTrafficing`named `TextView` in the same `MainActivity` which is not possible as it is not present in `activity_main` and which is present in another `xml`. So you are getting `NullPointerException` there.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Would I have to access the text view from the `what is human trafficing` fragment since it has the reference to the correct layout? Then start the fragment transaction in that fragment?

Comment: @Davep You can access the `textview` if and only if you have inflated the related `xml`

Comment: Almost. We're accessing the text view through it's id. That's stored in a separate file `R.id.`... Why must the xml be inflated to know that that text view exists?

Comment: Initially we inflate the `SplashScreen` fragment. That holds the `what is human trafficing` text view. So I should be able to get a reference to that text view right?

Comment: @Davep `whatIsHumanTrafficing  textview` will be accessible only in `whatIsHumanTrafficing Fragment` and not in `MainActivity`

Comment: can I create a view and inflate from the layout to access the text view through `view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);` What errors could this cause?

Comment: @Davep yes you can

Comment: So within the `MainActivity.java` I changed `onCreate` to `onCreateView`. Then I added `ViewGroup container, LayoutInflater inflater` to its parameters so that I could inflate the `splash_screen`'s view that's currently living in a `FrameLayout` as a fragment in `activity_main.xml`. When I do this and run the app nothing shows up on the screen.